# HTML. Таблица заголовок

Tags: html, css

Использую таблицу для вывода данных. У меня есть 4 заголовка в виде

```
<tr>
<th>Урок</th>
<th>Класс</th>
<th>Предмет</th>
<th>Кабинет</th>
</tr>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы над ними всеми был еще один заголовок ДНЯ НЕДЕЛИ.

[image: html]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не уверен, что так писать законно, но вряд ли разметочная полиция арестует. Всю магию делает `colspan="4"`, который указывает, сколько столбиков под (над) собой будет объединять указанный блок.

```css
/* ненужная декорация */
.table {border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #223148;}

.table th {color: #d3b167; padding: 4px 20px;}
.table td {
  color: #ddd; 
  border: 1px solid #65a1a9; 
  padding: 4px;
}

th.day { color: orange; font-size: 20px; }
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr><th class="day" colspan="4">• Понедельник •</th></tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Урок</th>
    <th>Класс</th>
    <th>Предмет</th>
    <th>Кабинет</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>111</td>
    <td>111</td>
    <td>111</td>
    <td>111</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: У столбцов нет верха и низа - они же не строки.